# Changing the colour of a UIButton based on its tag

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

Got a bunch of UIButtons, some of which need to change colour depending on circumstance, and currently it is handled like thus:

```
UIButton *button;
button = [self.view viewWithTag:positionInArray];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
button = [self.view viewWithTag:positionInArray-1];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
button = [self.view viewWithTag:positionInArray+3];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]]
button = [self.view viewWithTag:positionInArray+4];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
```

It works, but the code that sets a button to a tag throws this warning:

"Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UIButton *__strong' with an expression of type 'UIView *'"

How would I go about doing this correctly?

Comment: You can cast to (UIButton *) but it still looks like it could be done in a nicer way.

Comment: How would I do that? I've never dabbled in this before and a solution that doesn't throw a warning is at least better than one that does, even if it isn't pretty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast your UIViews to UIButtons like this:

```
button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:positionInArray];
```

It is best though to verify that your views are actually buttons by doing something like:

```
UIView *button = [self.view viewWithTag:positionInArray];
if ([button isKindOfClass[UIButton class]] {
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]]; 
}
```

In this example there is no need to caste to UIButton because UIViews have this method too. You would just want the if-statement if you only wanted to change UIButton's colors.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, that `viewWithTag:` may return any subclass of UIView. If you know that it will return a UIButton for sure you can cast it like this:

```
button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:positionInArray];
```

This will hide the warning, but may produce unexpected result when the view isn't a button! A nicer solution would be to check if the returned UIView subclass is a UIButton:

```
UIView *view = [self.view viewWithTag:positionInArray];
if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
   button = (UIButton *)view;
   [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
} else {
   NSLog(@"Ooops, something went wrong! View is not a kind of UIButton.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `viewWithTag:` returns a `UIView` because it can be of any subclass of `UIView`, including `UIButton`.

This is design dependent, if you don't have any other subview that has this tag, then you should simply cast the result to a UIButton like the other answers and be done with it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Downcasting alternative**

viewWithTag: returns a UIView, but it may point to a whatever subclass of UIView object.
Since polymorphism is valid, and the messaging is dynamic, you can just do that:

```
UIView *button;
button = [self.view viewWithTag:positionInArray];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
```

You inherit the backgroundColor from UIView, so there isn't any problem.
However you can always use the type id, which is a kind of "jolly".